# Netbeans does not see custom *.tagx in my Maven war dependency

Tags: maven-2, netbeans, jsp-tags

I have this scenarion in my project:

- Maven2 for dependency management
- One project 'common-web' (war) contains all images, css files, js files, layout files etc. It also contains custom tags (*.tagx files) that we use in our project. They are located in `WEB-INF\tags` direcotry.
- Second project (also war) has dependency on common-web, we use those custom tags in our *.jsp files by importing them in this way:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="custom" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
```

This works great in runtime, but is a big problem during development, because NetBeans does not see those custom tags and does not give me Intellisence.

In Eclipse I managed to work around this issue by linking tags directory in this second project. Can I do something similar in NetBeans? Or is there any better way to work around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'm no NetBeans export so apologies if this makes no sense, but I understand from [this article](http://www.java-tips.org/java-tutorials/tutorials/introduction-to-jstl-using-netbeans-3.html) that it will discover taglibs in referenced jars.

Would it be possible to move the shared tags into a jar and reference it in both wars instead of trying to have one war reference another? If the taglibs jar project is deployed to the Maven repository it would be managed by Maven and available to both projects.